# Parent Theme update was not showing on the update page

Tags: updates, parent-theme

I'm a novice user and looking for some help with a wordpress site that I am maintaining. I have a parent and a child theme set up and both had a recent update available. However the parent theme update was not showing on the Update page, and now after updating the parent theme there are problems saving changes pages.

Any idea why this would be happening? Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: How did you update if there wasn’t an update available? Did you update it manually? What theme is this? Are you sure it wasn’t a ‘starter’ theme? Those often release new versions, but those updates are often only meant for new projects, and you’re not supposed to update existing themes.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes updated it manually . It was WordPress 5.2.3 running  Divi (Parent theme) & Child Theme. I assume you mean themes bundled with wordpress as 'starter' themes. I guess they were imported from another setup so no idea about that.